# Bash: Echo a variable whose name is the value of another variable

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

Suppose I have the following:

```
foo1=abc
i=1
a="FOO${i}"
echo ${${a}}
echo ${`echo $a`} # I also tried that
```

I am getting the error `bash: ${${a}}: bad substitution`.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006  and look for indirect variable reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use parameter indirection `${!parameter}` i.e. in your case `${!a}`:

```
$ foo1=abc
$ i=1
$ a="foo${i}"
$ echo "${!a}"
abc
```

From "Parameter Expansion" section of `man bash`:

> ${parameter}
>
> .......
>
> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), it introduces a level of variable indirection.  Bash uses the
> value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of
> the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in
> the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter
> itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval` for this (and it would work with any POSIX shell, including bash):

```
eval 'echo $'$a
```

To illustrate:

```
#!/bin/bash -i

PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
PS2='Second prompt \u@\h:\w\$ '
PS3='Third prompt \u@\h:\w\$ '
echo "PS1:$PS1"
for n in 3 2 1
do
        eval 'PS0="$PS'$n'"'
        echo "$PS0"
done
```

produces (call the script "foo"):

```
$ ./foo
PS1:${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ 
Third prompt \u@\h:\w\$ 
Second prompt \u@\h:\w\$ 
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

Comment: I originally found this solution and was unable to make it work with my script (which had to do with `$PS1` setting. It bsaically had to set PS1 to PS11, PS12, etc depending on input (1,2,etc).

Comment: Thanks, it works well in pure `sh` too, useful trick on small bash-less docker images!