# A variable inside an another variable

Tags: bash, variable, for

I have these variables

```
a1=0.017
a2=0.2
a3=10.7
a4=20.9
a5=35.4

for ((x=1; x<=5; x++))
do
 for i in a${x}
 do
 echo "Welcome $i times"
 done
done
```

The output must be:

```
"Welcome 0.017 times"
"Welcome 0.2 times"
"Welcome 10.7 times"
"Welcome 20.9 times"
"Welcome 35.4 times"
```

But my output now is

```
Welcome a1 times
Welcome a2 times
Welcome a3 times
Welcome a4 times
Welcome a5 times
```

How cam I print a1 as $a1 in the way to have "10" ?

Otherwise I have to do this:

```
for i in $a1 $a2 $a3 $a4 $a5
do
 echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

The problem is that I have more than 100 "a" variables and I can not use the last option above

Are good also new suggestion outside of "loops"

Many thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're not putting the data in an `a` array? E.g. as `a[0]=10.1; a[1]=20.5` etc... And then loop with `for value in "${a[@]}"; do ...; done`.

Comment: It depends what shell you are using - in bash, you could use *indirection* like `echo "Welcome ${!i} times"` - see for example [Bash: Echo a variable whose name is the value of another variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270140/bash-echo-a-variable-whose-name-is-the-value-of-another-variable)

Comment: Kusalananda: no, there is not, just I have hard time to use correctly an array ... how can I use an array inside a loop please?

Comment: steeldriver: ok, I will try! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not hard to accomplish what you asked for:

```
a1=0.017
a2=0.2
a3=10.7
a4=20.9
a5=35.4

for ((x = 1; x <= 5; x++)); do
    var="a${x}"
    echo "Welcome ${!var} times"
done
```

It would have been simpler to make `a` an array variable, though:

```
a=(
    0.017
    0.2
    10.7
    20.9
    35.4
)

for x in "${a[@]}"; do
    echo "Welcome ${x} times"
done
```

Comment: Many thanks! The second code, array, is perfect for me! Thank you guys !!!

Comment: @EmmaAthan if you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.