# bash script, accessing pre-defined variables using for loop substitution

Tags: linux, bash, for

Heres the bash script:

```
ALL="2 3"

VC2="https://someaddress.acme.com"
VC3="https://someotheraddress.acme.com"

hosts2='12
13
14'

hosts3='15
16
17'

for i in $ALL
do
```

Here is where i want the substitution but no matter what i use it doesn't work.  I tried all of the following

```
     VC="$VC$i"
     VC="${VC$i}"
     VC="$(VC$i)"
     VC=$(VC$i)

     HOSTS="$hosts$i"
     echo "$VC"
     echo "$HOSTS"
```

the output i need is for each of the numbers in the ALL variable to then equal the predefined VC and hosts variables. i.e.

When i=2:

```
i=2
VC="https://someaddress.acme.com"
HOSTS='12
13
14'
```

and when i=3

```
i=3
VC="https://someotheraddress.acme.com"
HOSTS='15
16
17'
```

Thanks in advance.

Thomas

Comment: You can use indirection / namerefs as described here [Bash: Echo a variable whose name is the value of another variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270140/bash-echo-a-variable-whose-name-is-the-value-of-another-variable) however consider using indexed array variables instead.

Comment: Better, use arrays instead of splitting strings on either space or newline

Comment: I did see the array route, i couldn't figure out how it was pertinent, i wasn't splitting anything. i am replacing variables!.. thanks.

Comment: @steedrivers answer did the trick.. i saw references to arrays, but i couldn't get it to work for my example.